# Calendar widget showing the wrong event dates

Tags: calendar, app-widgets, htc-sense, google-calendar

Am I the only one experiencing this? The calendar widget is showing the correct day but the event shown next to it is in 2 days and it shows for tomorrow. Perfect example (see attached image): today is 2 November 2012 and daylight savings time in on 4 November 2012; yet it says it will occur tomorrow.

My phone specifics:

- HTC Inspire 4G
- Android version 2.3.5
- HTC Sense 3.0

[image: wrong calendar date in widget]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a bug in the app, but I rarely use the calendar widget.

It is also possible that this has been casued by the time change, or that you are in the afternoon.

However, you could try erasing all data on the app, and clearing it's cache, then trying again.

Comment: It's not because of the time change because it's been going on for a long time with many events.

Comment: I've cleared all the data for the calendar and widget, and it worked fine for about 12 hours. Now it's back to the same issue. Then I cleared it again, but this time won't even show the right time at all.

Comment: The issue is still persistent.

Comment: This is most likely a bug since it's been persistent for a very long time.